# import error no module named srv

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am struggling to progress the error (below) which I have encountered when completing this part of the tutorial [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/ExaminingServiceClient)

I'm not sure why the script I have literally copied over won't work. I have spent an hour or so trying to figure it out but can't solve it..

The code message:

```
danny@danny:~/catkin_ws$  rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/danny/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/add_two_ints_server.py", line 3, in <module>
    from beginner_tutorials.srv import *
ImportError: No module named srv
danny@danny:~/catkin_ws$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271274/import-error-no-module-named-srv/) by [danny5555](https://answers.ros.org/users/31904/danny5555/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-09-29**:
After compile your package/service with `catkin_make`, try to `source catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We'll need more to go off of than what you've given us. Are you going through the tutorials in order? Did you go through the [Creating a ROS msg and srv](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) and [Writing a Simple Service and Client (Python)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29) tutorials before trying run that particular tutorial? If you didn't do both of those then you will get that error.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Trayach_](https://answers.ros.org/users/57527/trayach_/) on 2020-08-09**:
I've done both , but also it is indicating error like this...
**ImportError: No module named beginner_tutorials.srv**
Not able to resolve it, could you help me with it ?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-08-09**:
You should create a new question and reference this one

**Comment by [Trayach_](https://answers.ros.org/users/57527/trayach_/) on 2020-08-09**:
while executing this  **rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_server.py**
im getting this error...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/chetan/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/add_two_ints_server.py", line 3, in 
from beginner_tutorials.srv import AddTwoInts,AddTwoIntsResponse
ImportError: No module named beginner_tutorials.srv

Would you help me with it ?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-08-09**:
@CubeC, comments are an inappropriate place to solve problems like that. Please create a new question, it's easier to work on a problem and it will get more visibility than using comments